# Use sed to replace string with whois command output

Tags: linux, sed, whois

I have a text file, containing the string `${whois}`.

I wish to replace `${whois}` with a `whois` command output of an IP address or domain. The result of a `whois` is pretty long and it generally goes wrong with everything I've tried to far.

I get errors such as `unterminated 's' command` or `invalid regular expressions`, and so on.

Can anyone provide me a working command that replaces the keyword `${whois}` with a `whois` output of a domain or IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$ whois > whois_out.txt
$ sed -e '/${whois}/r whois_out.txt' -e '//d' input_file.txt
```

- First save the output of command in a file
- Then use [r command for robust replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40699902/4082052) and delete the matching line

Comment: Works! I forgot to mention one thing; The output goes into a .html file, meaning the enters get screwed up. Is there a way to insert <br/> tags instead of enters?

Comment: you can process the `whois_out.txt` file whatever way you like using sed/awk/perl/other-text processing commands..  and then pass it on to this `sed` command... try it out.. see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/topics for examples if you face difficulties.. and then if you are stuck, you can ask another question...